# Resize an Image (on the fly) not working

Tags: image, resize

I am using this script from Bit Repository.
`<IMG SRC="resize_image.php?image=sunset.jpg&new_width=32&new_height=32">`

My problem is that, it is not showing any image on my hosted server. 
http://www.belowyellow.dx.am/resize_image/demo.html

but it works on my localhost, hope somebody can help me with this. Thank you.

Source: http://www.bitrepository.com/resize-an-image-keeping-its-aspect-ratio-using-php-and-gd.html

Comment: Is resize_image.php present in same directory where demo.html present?

Comment: Try to open the PHP script directly and you'll see there are some errors : http://www.belowyellow.dx.am/resize_image/resize_image.php?image=sunset.jpg&new_width=32&new_height=32

Comment: does "resise_image.php work as intended ?"

Comment: `Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /srv/` is it posible  @zakinster that the hosted server blocked it!?

Comment: @yul757 that would be logical and you should be able to get rid of it since it's not an essential feature.

Comment: ^_^ thank you @zakinster, I guess I just have to wait for my lunching date, since I was just hosting it for free yet, maybe some features are disabled. thanks again. hope to see your name on my website soon. ^_^

Comment: Note that `set_time_limit()` is used only to limit the execution time of your php script, if your hosting company disabled it it's probably because they're enforcing their own limit so the call to this function is completely useless in your production environment.

Comment: ^_^ thank you very much @zakinster! I remove the line and it works like a charm. Wew! now I can continue with my work. busy busy busy. take care.

Comment: @yul757 feel free to accept the answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at what your [PHP script](http://www.belowyellow.dx.am/resize_image/resize_image.php?image=sunset.jpg&new_width=32&new_height=32) returns before trying to embed it in an `img` tag, you'll see there are some warning before your image data.

Since PHP output text before your image output, it can't change the HTTP header anymore, so your image is output as text.

```
set_time_limit(10000);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

You should remove these two lines from resize_image.php. [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) is obviously disabled on your production server so the first line is useless and generates a warning. The [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in the second line is the real source of the problem here, it tells PHP to display **all** kind of warnings and notice. This kind of error reporting should only be used in a local debugging environment and **not on a production server**. If you remove this line, you'll get the default error reporting that shouldn't show any warning and your image should be correctly output.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> Show Resized Image </TITLE>
  <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Bit Repository">
  <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="src, image, resize, on the fly">
  <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="Display a resized image">
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
  <IMG SRC="resize_image.php?image=sunset.jpg&new_width=32&new_height=32">
 </BODY>
</HTML>` this sample is from the tutorial itself. I uploaded the whole demo folder, works on my localhost, but not on hosted server.